# cannot move out of index of `Vec<Layer>`

Tags: machine-learning, rust, borrow-checker

```
use fastapprox::faster::sigmoid;

pub struct Neuron {
    pub val: f32,
    pub con: Vec<f32>
}

impl Neuron {
    fn new(nextlaylen: u32) -> Neuron {
        let mut con = Vec::new();
        
        for _ in 0..nextlaylen {
            con.push(0.0);
        }

        Neuron { val: 0.0, con: con }
    }

    pub fn add(&self, layer: &mut Layer) {
        //  loop through neurons and add values with weights
        let mut counter = 0; 
        for i in 0..layer.neurons.len() {
            counter += 1;
            layer.neurons[i].val += self.val * self.con[counter];
        }
    }
}

pub struct Layer {
    pub neurons: Vec<Neuron>
}

impl Layer {
    pub fn new(size: u32, nextlaylen: u32) -> Layer {
        let mut neurons = Vec::new();

        for _ in 0..size {
            neurons.push(Neuron::new(nextlaylen));
        }

        Layer { neurons: neurons }
    }

    pub fn add(self, layer: &mut Layer) {
        //  add neurons together
        for i in 0..self.neurons.len() {
            self.neurons[i].add(layer);
        }

        for i in 0..layer.neurons.len() {
            layer.neurons[i].val = sigmoid(layer.neurons[i].val);
        }
    }
}

pub struct Model {
    pub layers: Vec<Layer>
}

impl Model {
    pub fn new(inputnodesamnt: u32, outputnodesamnt: u32, hiddenlayersamnt: u32, neuronsperlayer: u32) -> Model {
        let mut layers = Vec::new();

        layers.push(Layer::new(inputnodesamnt, neuronsperlayer)); //    create input layer 

        //  create hidden layers
        for i in 0..hiddenlayersamnt {
            if i != hiddenlayersamnt - 1 {
                layers.push(Layer::new(neuronsperlayer, neuronsperlayer));
            }
            else {
                layers.push(Layer::new(neuronsperlayer, outputnodesamnt));
            }
        }
        
        layers.push(Layer::new(outputnodesamnt, 0)); //    create output layer

        Model { layers: layers }
    }

    pub fn process(self) {
        for i in 0..self.layers.len() {
            self.layers[i].add(&mut self.layers[i + 1]);
        }
    }
}

pub struct Output {
    pub nodevaluearr: Vec<f32>
}

fn main() {
}
```

the error I get is this:

```
   error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Layer>`
     --> src/main.rs:83:13
      |
    83|             self.layers[i].add(&mut self.layers[i + 1]);
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Layer`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    
   For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
   error: could not compile `neuralnetrust` due to previous error
   The terminal process "cargo 'run', '--package', 'neuralnetrust', '--bin', 'neuralnetrust'" failed to launch (exit code: 101).
```

I'm trying to make a simple neural net.

also, does anybody have any good resources for learning about the borrow checker?

Answer (score 0):

Your `add` method takes ownership of `self`, when in reality you probably want to take `&self`. When you have a function which takes `self` instead of `&self` or `&mut self`, then when you call it on an object that object gets passed into the function and you cannot access it again (assuming it's not [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html)) after that since Rust has move semantics by default. If you want to learn more about Rust's memory model then I'd spend some time with [this chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) of the book.

Comment: now it says `cannot borrow self.layers as mutable more than once at a time`